# Heroku Spring Java Error: No such file or directory

Tags: java, spring, git, maven, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app on Heroku. I push it just fine, and my Procfile gets pushed. But when I try to run the app I get a "Error:No such file or directory"

I don't know what's going on. I can't even do a heroku run bash. I get the same error: "Error:No such file or directory"

It's like it's not actually pushing any files. But I attached my github account as a remote just so I can see what's being pushed, and it's all there. So I don't know what's going on. Any ideas?

Error from logs when trying to run:

```
←[36m2013-10-09T20:02:38.725988+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from crashed to starting
←[36m2013-10-09T20:02:44.039042+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `java -     Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port
 14050 target/*.war`
←[36m2013-10-09T20:02:44.701104+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Error: No such file or directory
←[36m2013-10-09T20:02:45.817542+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 126
```

Error when trying to run bash:

```
$ heroku run bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.6812
Error: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It looks like heroku couldn't find war file. I am not sure how "run bash" works but you may need to run maven package or install before that.